# Sequence Mining using arulesSequence package in R

Tags: r, data-mining, arules, sequence-analysis

I am trying to learn about Sequence Mining, and I ran the following code from [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Sequence_Mining/SPADE) as an example. The cspade function has taken over 30 minutes to run (and is still running) when the example shows that it should take less than a second. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

```
install.packages("arules")
install.packages("arulesSequences")

library(Matrix)
library(arules)
library(arulesSequences)

x <- read_baskets(con = system.file("misc", "zaki.txt", package = "arulesSequences"), info = c("sequenceID","eventID","SIZE"))
as(x, "data.frame")

s1 <- cspade(x, parameter = list(support = 0.4), control = list(verbose =TRUE))
```

Comment: Hmm maybe update your packages? The example works fine here.

Comment: It says "All packages are up to date." I am using R version 3.2.2, arules version 1.2-1, and arulesSequences is version 0.2-11.

Comment: same here, plus Matrix_1.2-2 .

Comment: Strange. I get `R> s1 <- cspade(x, parameter = list(support = 0.4), control = list(verbose =TRUE))

parameter specification:
support : 0.4
maxsize :  10
maxlen  :  10

algorithmic control:
bfstype  : FALSE
verbose  :  TRUE
summary  : FALSE
tidLists : FALSE

preprocessing ... 1 partition(s), 0 MB [0.018s]
mining transactions ... 0 MB [0.013s]
reading sequences ... [0.016s]

total elapsed time: 0.047s` 
so it is done in 47ms. (I use the same versions you do on Linux)

Comment: When I updated to RStudio v0.99.764 Preview the code worked. Thank you for your suggestions!